# MongoDB denormalization vs one-off initial query

Tags: mongodb, normalization, denormalization, nosql

I have a blog post like application. Users and Projects are stored in two different collections, i.e., many-to-many. A user might have 2-10 projects. A project might have 5-100 users, normally around 10. Post is another collection with objects like:

```
{
    "project_id": 123,
    "user_id": 456,
    "text": "some text",
    "comments": [{Comment object}]
}
```

Currently I use a normalization approach. I fire an one-off query to retrieve all current user's project names with project usernames when the application first loading. Then store them within a global variable so that it's accessible everywhere in my application. The only one drawback of this approach is the initial loading time would be a bit longer depending on how many projects you have and how many users are in your projects. It doesn't feel like a big deal.

However, many articles have suggested use denormalization. I do know the pros and cons. Since project_name and user_name exist in too many fields and different collections. It could be a long running task to propagate changes if project name or user name has been modified. That said, this won't happen very frequently.

Just wanna know if my current approach makes sense. Or denormalization can also be a good practice in terms of MongoDB. Please discuss and advise. Thanks.